# Use browser console to select drop down boxes in webpage table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

First, this is my first project outside VBA and I thought it would be easy... maybe not.

We have a client website that we fill out a form in. It is over 400 rows of just selecting "Yes" from a drop down menu. I do not have any ability to change the HTML code, other than the session version. Is it possible to use the in-browser console to identify the HTML element, and select a certain option? Below is the tables code showing what would need changed, and a version of stuff I have tried before. The browser console just says 'undefined' to what I try.

```
<select class="row" id="17.5.1" style="width:350px;font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:13px;" onchange="OnChangeElement(id)"><option></option><option selected="">Yes</option><option>No</option><option>NA</option></select>
```

What I have tried in the console, one of the many variations

```
function loop(tested){
var i;
for(i=1; i<20; i++){
//HTMLSelectElement("17.5.1");
//select.getOptionByValue("No");
//select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);
$("17.5.1").getOptionByValue('No').setSelectedAttribute(option, true);
}
}
```

I know almost no java... So I apologize if I do not know more.

Thanks!!

Comment: "I know almost no java" JavaSript, also known as Java for short :) https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/8jk0ii/javascript_also_known_as_java_for_short/

Comment: Ah man all r/ProgrammerHumor jokes go over my head :,(

Comment: *Ah I believe the joke is that Java and JavaScript are, in fact, not the same language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll want to select all of the `<select>` elements from the document.

```
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
```

And then loop over each select element in a loop to manipulate each `<select>` tag. In the example below the singular `select` constant is the current select element that we are looping over.

```
for (const select of selects) {
  ...
}
```

Then inside the loop you'll want to see the `options` of each `select` element, so we can see which ones have the values that you are looking for. Loop again over all the options by first converting the `HTMLOptionsCollection`, which is an object with all options, to an array and check if the `value` property equals the value that you try to set. This way you don't accidentally set the wrong value on the wrong `<select>` element. If it has that value, set the value directly on the select element.

```
for (const select of selects) {
  const { options } = select;
  const hasValue = Array.from(options).some((option) => option.textContent === 'Yes');
  if (hasValue) {
    select.value = 'Yes';
  }
}
```

Or when you only have to select a single element by id use:

```
const select = document.getElementById('17.5.1');
const { options } = select;
const hasValue = Array.from(options).some((option) => option.textContent === 'Yes');
if (hasValue) {
  select.value = 'Yes';
}
```

Comment: I have a variable to update the element ID. Is there somewhere in the solution to put the specific element to edit? Or does the


`const selects = document.querySelectorAll(select);`


select every element?

Thanks so much!

Comment: That line does indeed select all `<select>` elements. Though I forgot to make `(select)` a string like so `const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');`. But all add a snippet for selecting only that single select element.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a huge step forward and excatly what I was looking for. When I put it in the console and selected a particular cell to test, I got the two issues below. Does that mean I cannot run a script to select options?


`Cannot convert null or undefined to object

HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR)POST - https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0/?qsp=true&content-type=application%2Fbond-compact-binary&client-id=NO_AUTH&sdk-version=AWT-Web-JS-1.8.5&x-apikey=a387cfcf6011...etc`

Comment: You're welcome. Those errors are completely unrelated to the code I provided.